# DATEVALUE Comparison Issue

Tags: excel

Everyone:

I have a date 12/26/2020 formatted as short date in cell C26.

I am only doing two comparisons:

```
=$C26>=DATEVALUE("8/2/2020")
=$C26<=DATEVALUE("1/23/2021")
```

I am expecting both of those to be TRUE, but the first one is returning TRUE and the other is returning FALSE. The second statement becomes true only when I do `=DATEVALUE($C26)<=DATEVALUE("1/23/2021")`. Why is that?

Thank you,
Cin

Comment: What you have in C26 is text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: @BigBen Even though C26 is formatted as "Short Date"?

Comment: Yes, that's right @BigBen. I did not reproduce the problem correctly. When $C26 =  ````"12/26/2020"```` I was able to reproduce the issue. When it is simply ````12/26/2020```` then the formulas work as expected. Revoked my answer.

Comment: @Cinji18 format is separate from the underlying value.

Comment: Thank you so much, Pat and Ben.  Finally got what I was looking for.  I thought changing the format would change the underlying value.